# set savedInstanceState Bundle in Activity

Tags: android, android-savedstate

is there a way to manually set savedInstanceState Bundle ?

i need to start an activity in savedInstanceState mode that in onCreate the  savedInstanceState Bundle won't be null . my point is restoring an activity with my custom data . thanks

Comment: Why don't you just add extras to the intent starting activity and retrieve it from there?

Comment: i have to change a lot of code then , and i don't have time for debugging again  @mhenryk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will make your code unreadable and hard to upkeep in the future. Moreover, you will be working against the architecture of the platform.

**The correct approach is to send the data in the Intent which starts the `Activity`, or obtain all data in `onCreate` if bundle is null, like this:**

```
if(savedInstanceState == null)
    //Get data from db, resources etc.
else 
    //Do the restoring using the bundle, 
    //or just let it pass here and handle it in      
    //`onRestoreInstanceState`, both are correct
```

Please, don't try to find hack-fixes just because doing thigs the correct way takes a bit more time. It will pay off in the future! :-)

As a side note, please remember, that `Intent` starting an `Activity` should not hold big chunks of data, as there is a 1mb cross-process limit for data transferred between components at a time.